# How to get native keyboard autosuggestion string value

Tags: ios, keyboard

I made a page which contained a UITextFiled and a view that presented search result and I want to change the triggering conditions of the search. The original triggering conditions was changing the input text of textField and I want to make some change. I hope the search is triggered only when user touch the keyboard autocorrection. Could someone give me some advance, thank you!
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try implementing UITextChecker like this. The last two lines are the print statement for two types. One is for guesses words when misspelled occurred and the other is for dictionary words. The arrPredectiveText array contains words sequentially like dictionary. You can get suggestions from this.

Call the suggestionsForCustomKeyboard method with some string that you are typing.

```
-(void)suggestionsForCustomKeyboard:(NSString *)word{
    if ([currentString length] >= 1) {

    UITextChecker *textChecker = [[UITextChecker alloc] init];
    NSRange misspelledRange = [textChecker
                               rangeOfMisspelledWordInString:currentString
                               range:NSMakeRange(0, [currentString length])
                               startingAt:0
                               wrap:NO
                               language:@"en_US"];


    if (misspelledRange.location != NSNotFound) {

        guesses = [textChecker guessesForWordRange:misspelledRange
                                          inString:currentString
                                          language:@"en_US"];
        NSLog(@"First guess: %@", [guesses firstObject]);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Textchecker Not found");
        autocorrectedText = @"";
    }

    if (arrPredectiveText.count >= 2){
        suggestionOne = [arrPredectiveText objectAtIndex:0];
        suggestionTwo = [arrPredectiveText objectAtIndex:1];
    }
    else if (arrPredectiveText.count == 1 && guesses.count >= 1) {
        suggestionOne = [arrPredectiveText firstObject];
        suggestionTwo = [guesses firstObject];
    }else if (arrPredectiveText.count == 0 && guesses.count > 0){
        suggestionOne = [guesses firstObject];
        if (guesses.count > 1) {
            suggestionTwo = [guesses objectAtIndex:1];
        }
    }

    NSLog(@"Textchecker all guess: %@", guesses);
    NSLog(@"Prediction: %@",arrPredectiveText);

}
```